# High school pigeonhole principle question

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

Let p(x) be a polynomial with real coefficients and such that the product of all the roots is negative.
Show that if the degree of p(x) is 6, then p(x) has at least one positive root.

Comment: Do you have any ideas/progress you'd like to share?

Comment: So basically I reached a standstill because for a polynomial with 6 distinct zeros, it always needs to have an odd number of negative zeros to keep the product negative. But what happens in a degree 6 polynomial like (x+1)(x+1)(x+2)(x+3)(x+4)(x+5) where we have a duplicate zero? Because here product of zeros will be -1*-2*-3*-4*-5 = negative and we don't have a positive root.

Comment: It sounds like you're nearly there. In the case of the duplicate root, we should count that root twice in the product, so $(-1)^2(-2)(-3)(-4)(-5)$ is positive. So repeated roots don't really make a difference. But there's one extra subtlety that you're missing -- who said the polynomial need have six *real* roots? What about complex ones?

Comment: Can a complex number be positive? As in is (1 - i) positive or negative?

Comment: Complex numbers are neither positive or negative. But the condition that your polynomial has *real* coefficients gives you some extra information about the (complex) roots

Answer (score 1):

If a polynomial has real coefficients then for any complex root $z$, the conjugate $\bar{z}$, is also a root .

And $z\cdot \bar{z}=|z|^2>0$.

Therefore if the degree is $6$ it can have $0,2,4,6$ real roots, including multiple roots.

If the product of all roots is negative, then real roots can't be all negative: there must be a positive one, at least.